# dapper.net releasing cached memory

Tags: .net, caching, memory, orm, dapper

I am new to dapper (accually about to use it). I was wondering how it works. It caches some results, so it's faster to get it later on. On the github page, it does not says anything about releasing memory. I am aware of performance of this nuget, but isn't there any danger about memory overflow or sth? Is the cached memory released in some way sometimes?

Comment: "It caches some results, so it's faster to get it later on." - no it doesn't; it caches the result of meta-programming for your query and results **shape**. It never never caches actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web tier often reached 100% CPU due to the volume of queries. With hundreds of calls per second, the CPU overhead from LINQ to SQL constructing a dynamic method for every call placed too much of a burden on the web servers.

To resolve this problem, Dapper.Net caches information about every query. This comprehensive caching helps it to generate objects from queries about twice as fast as LINQ to SQL. Currently caching is handled by two ConcurrentDictionary objects, which are never cleared. In the future the caching algorithm may use a LRU cache to reduce memory pressure.

Comment: There may be a big in the clearing of those dictionaries - it is on my list

Comment: May be but i will recommend dapper over other ORM's

Comment: EF Core 6 is now comparable to dapper. I would also note, dapper is great, if you don't use it wrong. A simple mistake in dynamic strings and you're left with leaky systems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#improved-performance-on-techempower-fortunes